# Java serialization of a value in a Scala singleton object

Tags: scala, serialization

I have Scala singleton objects `Works` and `Broken` that look very similar:

```
object Works {
  def i = ???
  val factory = new Serializable {
    def get = i
  }
}

object Broken extends A

trait A {
  def i = ???
  val factory = new Serializable {
    def get = i
  }
}
```

What I'd like to understand is why is `Works.factory` serializable but `Broken.factory` isn't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To serialise a class all members must also be serialisable. However consider `-Xprint:jvm` output of the anonymous `new Serializable` in `trait A`

```
  final class anon$1 extends Object with java.io.Serializable {
    def get(): Nothing = anon$1.this.$outer.i();
    <synthetic> <paramaccessor> <artifact> private[this] val $outer: $line58.iw$A = _;
    def <init>($outer: $line58.iw$A): <$anon: Object> = {
      if ($outer.eq(null))
        throw null
      else
        anon$1.this.$outer = $outer;
      anon$1.super.<init>();
      ()
    }
  }
```

In particular note the member

```
<synthetic> <paramaccessor> <artifact> private[this] val $outer: $line58.iw$A = _;
```

The class of instance referenced by `$outer` is `A`, however `trait A` has **not** been declared as `Serializable`. Therefore serialisation of anonymous class referenced by `Broken.factory` fails.

On the other hand, consider `-Xprint:jvm` output of the anonymous `new Serializable` in `object Works`

```
  final class anon$1 extends Object with java.io.Serializable {
    def get(): Nothing = iw$Works.this.i();
    def <init>(): <$anon: Object> = {
      anon$1.super.<init>();
      ()
    }
  }
```

Notice there is no member (similar to `$outer`) that is not `Serializable`. Therefore serialisation of anonymous class referenced by `Works.factory` succeeds.

The fix is to make trait `A` serialisiable like so

```
trait A extends Serializable { ... }
```

however [Java Object Serialization Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/specs/serialization/serial-arch.html#the-serializable-interface) warns

> Serialization of inner classes (i.e., nested classes that are not
>   static member classes), including local and anonymous classes, is
>   strongly discouraged for several reasons. Because inner classes
>   declared in non-static contexts contain implicit non-transient
>   references to enclosing class instances, serializing such an inner
>   class instance will result in serialization of its associated outer
>   class instance as well.